# How to pass the local scope array to the event handler?

Tags: jquery

I have a local scope array which I am trying to pass to a click event handler. However, I am unable to pass the array to the click handler.

This is my code

```
$("ul.tabs-2 li").click(function (event, myarray) {
    console.log('i am called');
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(tabclicked === '#one') {

    } else if(tabclicked === '#two') {

    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {

    var myarray = [
        [
            "01-Oct",
            1064.8,
            1089,
            1046.05,
            1055.35
        ],
        [
            "05-Oct",
            1065,
            1110,
            1055,
            1106.45
        ],
        [
            "06-Oct",
            1115,
            1145,
            1087.95,
            1094.4
        ]
    ];

    $('ul.tabs-2 li:eq(0)').click(event, myarray);
});
```

and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/10/

Could you please tell me how to resolve the issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shortly, you can use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/11/).

...

Firstly, you should move your click event binding into ready() block. Or else your event binding can't register to dom. Then, if you want to use all data of myarray, you should be wrapped it with an another array. Because, if you send this myarray data like that, you must handle that data in your event trigger the following;

```
$("ul.tabs-2 li").on('click', function(event, arr1, arr2, arr3) { ... }
```

**Edit:**

I updated my answer on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/13/). I don't know what you want to do in #one, #two conditions. So I pressed just console logs in conditions.

Comment: Thank you , but why this is data is unavialable under else if (tabclicked === '#two') condition ??

Comment: @PreethiJain you want to learn to pass data. And I wrote this solution. If you write exactly what you want, I try to help you. if I click data or chart links, what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

As per docs, you have to send the **eventData** before **handler** like:

```
$("ul.tabs-2 li").click(myarray, function (event) {
```

and you should put all the event bindings in doc ready block which ensures that DOM is ready and it will be able to register events for specific ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("ul.tabs-2 li").click(myarray, function(event) {
    console.log('i am called');
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if (tabclicked === '#one') {
      $('pre').html(myarray[$(this).index()].join(' '))
    } else if (tabclicked === '#two') {
      $('pre').html(myarray[$(this).index()].join(' '))
    }
  });

  var myarray = [
    ["01-Oct", 1064.8,  1089, 1046.05, 1055.35],
    ["05-Oct", 1065, 1110, 1055, 1106.45],
    ["06-Oct", 1115, 1145, 1087.95, 1094.4]
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>

<div id="divforhistoricresults" class="classhistoricaldataresults">
    <div class="list-container-2">
        <ul class="tabs-2 clearfix">
            <li class='default'><a href="#one">Data</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#two">Chart</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-container-2">
        <table id="one" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped"></table>
        <table id="two" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the myarray  is been a global scope know ??

Comment: @PreethiJain yes that is global so Doesn't it work for you. and you comment is not helping to understand the issue. be kind enough to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution would be to use the magic API called

```
bind(context)
```

You first create a plain function at the desired context-level.

```
listClickListener = function(evt) {
    console.log('i am called');
    var caller = $(evt.target);
    var tabclicked = $(caller).attr("href");
    if (tabclicked === '#one')
    {
        console.log("one clicked");
    }
    else if (tabclicked === '#two')
    {
        console.log("two clicked");
    }
    else {
        console.log(caller);
        console.log(evt);
    }
};
listClickListener.bind(this);
```

And then attach it to whatever

```
$("ul.tabs-2 li").on('click', listClickListener);
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/10/